# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Tags: errors, media-library

On a freshly built site running version 3.1.3 with the twentyten theme active and no plugins, when I click on "Media" to go the media manager, I'm getting this error:

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php on line 2390
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php on line 2399
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php on line 2399
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php on line 2399
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php on line 2399
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php on line 2399
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php on line 2399
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php on line 2399
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php on line 2399
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php:2390) in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\functions.php on line 851
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\query.php:2390) in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-includes\functions.php on line 852

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick look at source for that version shows parsing `post_status` argument. It's probably [this bug that got fixed in 3.2](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16824).

Upgrade. :)